# If $ab \neq ba$, prove that $aba \neq e$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If $a$ and $b$ are group elements and $ab \neq ba$, prove that $aba \neq e$ where $e$ is the identity.

This is an exercise from Contemporary Abstract Algebra. I am providing my answer here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Or more simply:

$aba=e\Rightarrow ab=a^{-1}$ (multiplying by $a^{-1}$ on the right) and also $aba=e\Rightarrow ba=a^{-1}$ (multiplying by $a^{-1}$ on the left). So $ab=ba$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume for the sake of contradiction that $aba = e$. Then $ab = a^{-1}$. We have $$baa^{-1} = b \implies baab = b \implies baa = e \implies aba = baa \implies ab = ba $$
Contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

If $aba=e$, then left-multiply *and* right-multiply by $a^{-1}$ to see that $b=a^{-2}$. So $a$ commutes with $b$ because $b$ is a power of $a$. So $aba=e\implies ab=ba$, and therefore $ab\neq ba\implies aba\neq e$.